# Clojure-koans run error:

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to learn Clojure by Clojure-koans; however, Clojure-koans could not run:

```
~/Downloads/clojure-koans-2012-10-18_18-42/script $> ./run
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main
```

But I can start clojure by `lein repl`. And by emacs `cider-jack-in`.

What should I do to get Clojure-koans run?

**Edit**: Problem solved by edit the dependencies in project.clj in src folder:
(changed to the latest clojure 1.6.0)

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
```

Should I answer my own question? or how could I mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 2):

Have you run `lein deps` in the project? From the documentation (https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans):

> The only things you'll need to run the Clojure Koans are:
>
> JRE 1.5 or higher
>
> clojure-1.5.1.jar
>
> You can use Leiningen to automatically install the Clojure jar in the right place. Leiningen will also get you a couple more jarfiles, including JLine, which allows you some of the functionality of readline (command-line history, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest either `cd .. && ./script/run` (I'm guessing the shell script may assume being run one directory up) or cloning the clojure-koans repo and running `lein koan run` (also from the project root directory).